# tableView reloadData will not remove previous UITextView that is programmatically placed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a UITableView with several different elements added programmatically. The one I'm having trouble with is the UITextView that displays correctly with correct color, size, font, etc... I have a button in one cell that increases the size of the font in the UITextView in another cell. It works fine and has no issues. The numerical value is placed in a Plist, and when you leave the view with the table and come back the size changes perfectly.

I've placed a reloadData in the button which does reload the table and gives the textView new size and resizes it to fit the new content plus resizes the cell perfectly. The issue I'm having is that when the reloadData is called, the old textView remains. So I have two texts, at two different sizes, or three or four and so on. How can I remove the previous textView when it's not set to global?

Everything is set up exactly how one would expect:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// cell with textView. Everything is instanced and created for just that cell with tags
UITextView *t = [self setSizeAndTextOfTextView];
[cell.contentView addSubview:t];

// cell with button. simple, alloc's and init inside cell. Calls method in same class
cell.contentView addSubview:button];

//method to increases font size
write to Plist the new size
[self.tableView reloadData]; <-- tableView is iboutlet that does reload table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you getting the cell in the first place? Are you reusing? If you are you don't want to add the textview as a subview again you want to retrieve the existing one and adjust it

UPDATE:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]) {
    UITextView *t = (UITextView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    //This version will take an existing textview and just resize it
    [self setSizeAndTextOfTextView:t];

} else {
    //This version creates a new text view
    UITextView *t = [self setSizeAndTextOfTextView];
    t.tag = 1
    [cell.contentView addSubview:t];
}
```

You'll probably need to do something similar with you button as well

The `reloadData` won't wipe the existing cells, just the data displayed, so you'll get an old one to reuse

Comment: I am reusing the cells. After I replace the data in the textView, I just reloadData?

Comment: Yep the cell you've got back already has a textView in it, maybe if you posted more code, for example your `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: There isn't any code to add. The only code I left out was the alloc and init methods and the tableView delegates. 
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 100.0f)];

Comment: @Tateyaku - You've left out how how you get `cell`.

Comment: The UITextView *t = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]; says assigning uiview to UITextView. Other than that, this seems like a great strategy!

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to add a cast, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 2):

You may consider creating a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` and associate that with your cell identifier. In your subclass, override the `prepareForReuse` method to set the cell back to a neutral state. Since cell objects are reused but are only initialized once, `prepareForReuse` is available to restore an already existing cell to its freshly initialized state.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm going to use this in some other cells that require much more alterations.

Comment: Yep, that's what it's intended for. Since it seems like this answer helped you can you accept it as an answer?